# Convert numbers 1-26 to A-Z?

Tags: db2

How can I convert the numbers in the range 1 through 26 to their respective letter position in the alphabet?

1 = A
2 = B
...
26 = Z

Comment: is your db2 installation using ascii or ebcdic? (because the last time i used db2 it was on a mainframe that used ebcdic)

Comment: ebcdic? I would suicide if my db used that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`CHR(#)`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000778.html) will give you the ASCII character, you just need to offset it based on the ASCII table:

e.g. A = 65, so you will need to add 64 to 1:

```
CHR(64 + #) = A if # is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) code is the numerical representation of a character such as 'a' or 'Z'. Therefore by looking at the table one can see that capital A has a value of 65 and Z has a value of 90. Adding 64 from each value in the range 1-26 will give you their corresponding letter.